# File expl3.sty not found when trying to compile a *.tex file with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, expl3

I've installed XeTeX to my Fedora 17 recently (before that, I was using pdfLaTeX). The main reason for switching to XeTeX was the [polyglossia](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) package I'd like to make use of. Unfortunately, whenever trying to compile a `*.tex` source file that includes `polyglossia` with xelatex, e.g.

```
xelatex file.tex
```

the following error message turns up:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty

! LaTeX Error: File `expl3.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

I therefore tried to install the `expl3` library, which is included in the [l3kernel](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel) package. Nonetheless, this didn't solve the problem since the package doesn't contain the file `expl3.sty` itself, only `expl3.dtx` (and `expl3.pdf`). So far I haven't been able to build `expl3.sty` from it (should be done using `xelatex expl3.dtx`? Sadly, doesn't work.)

Comment: Update your TeX distribution

Comment: @smh I installed the latest XeTeX version only a couple days ago, from the [official XeTeX site](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=xetex_linux#705c4129), I think it should be up to date.

Comment: What's your TeX distribution? MikTeX? What version?

Comment: You have to install `expl3` package. To install a package see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/55473#55473)

Comment: It is actually quite likely that your fontspec is too old and wants an old version of expl3. Is tex live installed from fedora repositories? If yes, remove existing expl3 and fontspec, and install the current versions of the l3* bundle and fontspec.  They come bundled as .tds.zip files which are extremely easy to install (i.e., unzip at the base of your tex tree).

Comment: Well, `tex -v` gives `TeX 3.141592 (Web2C 7.5.6)`, `latex -v` gives `pdfTeX using libpoppler 3.141592-1.40.3-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.6)`. Is it what you're asking about? Not sure how to tell my distribution & version another way.

Comment: I'm still pretty confused about which distro and version of TeX I actually have :). Originally, I used pdfTeX running on I-don't-know-which distribution (Web2C?). I also installed TeX Live from Fedora repositories (could this also be the source of my problems?). I followed @jon's instructions and successfully (?) installed `expl.sty`. When trying to compile the same code, I get: ! Package expl3 Error: Required primitives not found.

Comment: @HarishKumar: I tried to follow the given instructions (for TeX Live), but alas, the command `tlmgr` is unrecognized.

Comment: The best way is to not rely on Fedora's packaging and install a regular TeXLive installation.  See [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/2693).

Comment: This seems old.  There are two options: purge your installation and install TeX Live directly (as suggested), or (first!) remove respository-installed versions of the `expl3` and `fontspec` and then install the current versions, ideally using `.tds.zip` files.  The first option is easiest, but may not be realistic (e.g., bandwidth limits).  The second option is not particularly hard, but requires comfort with the command line and the willingness to track down all the offending files.  The biggest problem is that old `expl3` stuff has changed location compared to the `l3*` stuff. (con't)

Comment: ... you *must* purge *all* expl3 files first because of the location and file re-naming changes from about 2 years ago: they cause endless conflicts.  *Then* install: `fontspec.tds.zip`, `l3kernel.tds.zip`, `l3packages.tds.zip`, `l3experimental.tds.zip`.  If you plan to use `luatex`, then also install: `lualibs.tds.zip`, `luamplib.tds.zip`, `luaotfload.tds.zip`, `luatexbase.tds.zip`, `luatextra.tds.zip` --- along with the current binaries for `luatex`.  I'd also add the `oberdiek.tds.zip` bundle as it includes many useful facilities for the newer engines.

Comment: @jon: Thank you for your time, everything works just fine now.

Comment: @jon What should I do after instaling Tex Live?